# "Narrowing conversion from 'int' to 'char' inside { }" for legal values when cross compiling

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, cross-compiling

I have a C++ project that I compile both using `g++` on my machine (compiling to "host") and to an ARM processor using a cross compiler (in my case `arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-g++`). I am in the process of converting to C++0x/11 standart and there is an error I get when compiling initialization list, which I was able to reproduce in the following snippet:

```
int main(void) {
    char c[1] = {-108};
}
```

This program is seemingly correct as `-108` is a legal value for a `char`.
Compiling this with `g++` yields no error with the following command line:

```
g++ example.cc -std=c++0x
```

However, when I compile with the cross-compiler, like so:

```
arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-g++ example.cc -std=c++0x
```

I get the following error:

```
example.cc: In function 'int main()':
example.cc:2:22: error: narrowing conversion of '-0x0000000000000006c' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-fpermissive]
```

Since the value is legal, this seems like a bug. Can you explain why I get this error and what to do to solve it?

**Edit**: note that using positive values (e.g., `108`) is legal and does not result in an error on both compilers.

Comment: `char` might be unsigned on the target platform. Can you check?

Comment: @Brian, how do I check that?

Comment: @AndyThomas `std::is_signed<char>`? Or, rustically, `char(-1) < '\0'`

Comment: Do you get the same error for `108`? Also, early GCC implementations of c++0x were quite strict with the narrowing conversions. Maybe your cross-compiler is one of those. It *is* a narrowing conversion from `int` to `char` after all.

Comment: What happens if you declare it `signed char c[1]`?

Comment: @Columbo Also, `CHAR_MIN`

Comment: @juanchopanza no errors for positive values, see my edit.

Comment: @Barmar using `signed char` worked! Write it up as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you declare a variable as `char`, it's implementation-dependent whether it's signed or unsigned. If you need to be able to store negative values, you should declare it `signed` explicitly, rather than relying on the implementation-defined default.

```
signed char c[1] = { -108 };
```

Answer (score 11):

> Since the value is legal

How do you know that? `char`s signedness is implementation defined. And if it's unsigned, your code is ill-formed by narrowing - §8.5.4/7:

> A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion   
> […]
>    (7.4) —
>   **from an integer type […] to an integer type
>   that cannot represent all the values of the original type**, except
>   where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

§8.5.1/2:

> If the *initializer-clause* is an expression and a narrowing conversion (8.5.4) is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed.

However, if you need a signed `char`, use `signed char`.

```
signed char c[1] = {-108};
```

…is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

This should be even better:

```
signed char c[] = { (signed char)(-108) };
```

Because in brackets the value could be treated as int by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation compiling binutils in an arm cross-compiler with crosstool-ng, although my error was:

> i386.cc:3165:31: error: narrowing conversion of '144' from 'int' to 'char'

Since 144 is greater than signed char range of -128 to 127, I had to change the affected lines and return of the function to **unsigned char**.

I also needed to use **reinterpret_cast<char *>** in the return of the function as the result was being used to form a string sequence. This then compiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

All 8-bit values are distinctly representable by `char` object (on typical modern hardware) so it should be safe(*) to assign such a value.

The compiler won't emit a warning if the literal is of `char` type. An [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) allows you to provide a hexadecimal number as a character literal:

```cpp
int main(void) {
    char c[1] = {'\x94'};
}
```

This will compile without triggering `-Wnarrowing` on systems with either signed or unsigned `char` ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/jWKz6s6fE)).

(*) Safe here means no information will be lost, although the value may not be what you expect: -108 if `char` is signed and 148 is `char` is unsigned.